# Setting a datacontext via resources

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Evidently using "Resources" to set an control's DataContext does not do what I think. I'm trying to stick close to MVVM. The following is an experiment in setting DataContext.

The MainWindow has a TabControl with two tabs, each displaying my pet's name, initally "Sam". Clicking the "ChangeName" button on Tab 1 changes the pet's name (to "Daisy") as expected. It does not change on Tab 2.

The content of Tab 2 is a Page, with its own DataContext, SecondTabViewModel. So I need to adjust the DataContext in the TextBlock in order to get at MyPet's name. This compiles ok, and Intellisense brings up the right things, so somehow within the control is being set. But the pet's name does not change.

Does the "StaticResource" generate instantiate a new copy of MainWindow or something? Can someone help me out? I'd love to know why this doesn't work, and what *would* work. This strategy for setting local DataContext is supposed to work according to the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0 but I must be misreading.

To abbreviate I've omitted some of the code (the pet class. But everything seems to be ok there, in I'm able to change the name on the first tab The Pet class implements INotifyPropertyChanged, I'm using the right handler etc.)

**MainWindow.xmal**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp9"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="First Tab" Height="50">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyPet.Name}"/>
                    <Button Content="Change Name" 
                            Command="{Binding ChangePetNameCommand}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Second Tab" Height="50">
                <Frame Source="SecondTab.xaml"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

***MainWindowViewModel***

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public Pet MyPet { get; set; }
    public ICommand ChangePetNameCommand { get; set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        MyPet = new Pet();

        ChangePetNameCommand = 
            new RelayCommand(ChangePetName, (Object o) => true);
    }

    public void ChangePetName(object o)
    {
        MyPet.Name = "Daisy";
    }
}
```

***SecondTab.xmal***

```xml
<Page x:Class="WpfApp9.SecondTab"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp9"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="SecondTab">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:SecondTabViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="M"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource M},     
                                      Path = MyPet.Name}"/>                            
          </StackPanel> 
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

***SecondTabviewModel***

```cs
namespace WpfApp9
{
    public class SecondTabViewModel
    {
        public SecondTabViewModel()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="M"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

in SecondTab.xaml are creating a second MainWindowViewModel instance.

In other words, SecondTab does not operate on the original MainWindowViewModel.

You would somehow have to pass a reference to the original MainWindowViewModel instance to SecondTabViewModel.

---

Instead of using a Frame and a Page, SecondTab could perhaps be a UserControl that simply inherits the DataContext from its parent element, and you could pass a view model object like

```
<TabItem Header="Second Tab" Height="50">
    <local:SecondTab DataContext="{Binding SecondTabVM}"/>
</TabItem>
```

where `SecondTabVM` is a property of MainWindowViewModel that holds a SecondTabViewModel instance.